# org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkExecutionException

Tags: java, android, kotlin, gradle

I have an application made on Catalon, some errors appeared and I solved them by developing all libraries and versions, but there are problems that I could not solve, I will leave the error messages

```
starting the daemon as: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java -cp C:\Users\fadis\.gradle\jdks\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-compiler-embeddable\1.7.10\909803167c98606fcf22b4c848647c68e351d48d\kotlin-compiler-embeddable-1.7.10.jar;C:\Users\fadis\.gradle\jdks\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-reflect\1.7.10\165e600dfea6185cf5efa700756294cc4904dbeb\kotlin-reflect-1.7.10.jar;C:\Users\fadis\.gradle\jdks\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-stdlib\1.7.10\d2abf9e77736acc4450dc4a3f707fa2c10f5099d\kotlin-stdlib-1.7.10.jar;C:\Users\fadis\.gradle\jdks\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-script-runtime\1.7.10\c99c87a6988d8fd8d5142e9ed5c9f34a7cf561ee\kotlin-script-runtime-1.7.10.jar;C:\Users\fadis\.gradle\jdks\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-daemon-embeddable\1.7.10\3a9f7aef7080d3ae63126cbba4f827ed664f32fa\kotlin-daemon-embeddable-1.7.10.jar;C:\Users\fadis\.gradle\jdks\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.intellij.deps\trove4j\1.0.20200330\3afb14d5f9ceb459d724e907a21145e8ff394f02\trove4j-1.0.20200330.jar;C:\Users\fadis\.gradle\jdks\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\net.java.dev.jna\jna\5.6.0\330f2244e9030119ab3030fc3fededc86713d9cc\jna-5.6.0.jar;C:\Users\fadis\.gradle\jdks\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-stdlib-common\1.7.10\bac80c520d0a9e3f3673bc2658c6ed02ef45a76a\kotlin-stdlib-common-1.7.10.jar;C:\Users\fadis\.gradle\jdks\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains\annotations\13.0\919f0dfe192fb4e063e7dacadee7f8bb9a2672a9\annotations-13.0.jar -Djava.awt.headless=true -D$java.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1 -Xmx4608m -Dkotlin.environment.keepalive -ea org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.KotlinCompileDaemon --daemon-runFilesPath C:\Users\fadis\AppData\Local\kotlin\daemon --daemon-autoshutdownIdleSeconds=7200 --daemon-compilerClasspath C:\Users\fadis\.gradle\jdks\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-compiler-embeddable\1.7.10\909803167c98606fcf22b4c848647c68e351d48d\kotlin-compiler-embeddable-1.7.10.jar;C:\Users\fadis\.gradle\jdks\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-reflect\1.7.10\165e600dfea6185cf5efa700756294cc4904dbeb\kotlin-reflect-1.7.10.jar;C:\Users\fadis\.gradle\jdks\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-stdlib\1.7.10\d2abf9e77736acc4450dc4a3f707fa2c10f5099d\kotlin-stdlib-1.7.10.jar;C:\Users\fadis\.gradle\jdks\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-script-runtime\1.7.10\c99c87a6988d8fd8d5142e9ed5c9f34a7cf561ee\kotlin-script-runtime-1.7.10.jar;C:\Users\fadis\.gradle\jdks\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-daemon-embeddable\1.7.10\3a9f7aef7080d3ae63126cbba4f827ed664f32fa\kotlin-daemon-embeddable-1.7.10.jar;C:\Users\fadis\.gradle\jdks\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.intellij.deps\trove4j\1.0.20200330\3afb14d5f9ceb459d724e907a21145e8ff394f02\trove4j-1.0.20200330.jar;C:\Users\fadis\.gradle\jdks\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\net.java.dev.jna\jna\5.6.0\330f2244e9030119ab3030fc3fededc86713d9cc\jna-5.6.0.jar;C:\Users\fadis\.gradle\jdks\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-stdlib-common\1.7.10\bac80c520d0a9e3f3673bc2658c6ed02ef45a76a\kotlin-stdlib-common-1.7.10.jar;C:\Users\fadis\.gradle\jdks\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains\annotations\13.0\919f0dfe192fb4e063e7dacadee7f8bb9a2672a9\annotations-13.0.jar


Caused by: org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkExecutionException: A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable


Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzhz found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-base-21.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:21.1.0) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-19.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:19.0.0)


Caused by: org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkExecutionException: A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction

Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Compilation error. See log for more details


Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzhz found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-base-21.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:21.1.0) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-19.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:19.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzmz found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-base-21.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:21.1.0) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-19.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:19.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzna found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-base-21.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:21.1.0) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-19.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:19.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zznb found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-base-21.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:21.1.0) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-19.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:19.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zznc found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-base-21.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:21.1.0) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-19.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:19.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zznd found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-base-21.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:21.1.0) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-19.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:19.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzne found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-base-21.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:21.1.0) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-19.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:19.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zznf found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-base-21.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:21.1.0) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-19.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:19.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzfw found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-19.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:19.0.0) and jetified-play-services-measurement-base-21.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:21.1.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzha found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-base-21.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:21.1.0) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-19.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:19.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzhb found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-base-21.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:21.1.0) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-19.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:19.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzhc found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-base-21.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:21.1.0) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-19.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:19.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzhd found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-base-21.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:21.1.0) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-19.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:19.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzhe found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-base-21.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:21.1.0) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-19.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:19.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzhf found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-base-21.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:21.1.0) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-19.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:19.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzik found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-base-21.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:21.1.0) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-19.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:19.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzip found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-base-21.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:21.1.0) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-19.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:19.0.0)
```

---

### And this is the file of the grid after all modifications:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'

    // enable only if you want to use Firebase service
    //id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}
android {
    compileSdkVersion 32

    defaultConfig {
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        applicationId "com.salehfm.play2earn"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.1"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
            zipAlignEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro', 'proguard-rules-new.pro'
        }
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    namespace 'com.salehfm.play2earn'
}

dependencies {
    def lifecycle_version = "2.5.1"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:21.1.0"
    def multidex_version = "2.0.1"
    implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:$multidex_version"
    implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:${version}"
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar','*.arr'])
    implementation files('../libs/unity-ads.aar')
    implementation "androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:1.2.0"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
    implementation "androidx.preference:preference-ktx:1.2.0"
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime:2.7.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3'
    implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:5.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.0'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.2.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'
    implementation 'androidx.preference:preference-ktx:1.2.0'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:21.1.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:14.1.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.shimmer:shimmer:0.5.0@aar'
    implementation 'com.github.CanHub:Android-Image-Cropper:3.1.2'
    implementation('io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt:0.9.1')
    implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:5.2.0'
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1"

    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'

    implementation 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:6.11.0'
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

---

### the other file

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.13'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

---

Please if anyone knows a solution to this problem, tell me what to do.
I tried deleting all files, removing and reinstalling Android, but the problem is the same

Comment: Have you tried uncommenting `//id 'com.google.gms.google-services'`?

Answer (score 0):

I solved add in Android/App/build.gradle:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 33
    configurations {
        all*.exclude group: 'com.google.android.play', module: 'core'
    }
 .......
}

dependencies {
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.2.4"
implementation 'com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
```

don't forget to clean the project